# Alter HTML field using Java Code

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Is it possible that we can alter the field attribute such as the **class="required"** or the set is hidden in the HTML using JAVA code?

Comment: maybe... what have you tried?

Comment: Please do not hesitate to post the codes you have tried.

Comment: actually i dont have any idea at all how to do it. because i never alter HTML using from JAVA code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible? **YES** it is.

Is it **JAVA**? **No**, it isn't.

It is *Javascript*!

Just access your element through the DOM and change the `className` property.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('idOfTheElementToChangeClass').className += "required"; //I use += because otherwise it would override all the other classes(if set)
```

Comment: which mean i cant alter it from a Java file?

Comment: If you want to do it client-side then no, you can't

Comment: actually what i gonna do is to alter several JSP page. So, i think it is more easier if i can do the logic on a singgle JAVA file.

Comment: This code must be added in the HTML file, it doesn't matter if it is `.php`, `.jsp` or whatever, is the browser that reads it!

Comment: i dont want to do it client-side. which mean that, i gonna pull the data from a table. check what JSP file and which field that wanted to be alter. If i do it in javascript, i should alter each and every HTML right?

Comment: If I really understood what you want to do(and I'm not sure) then yes, you have

Comment: Okay thank you, i get it. But, is really cant do it from Java file even i dont ant it to be client side?

Comment: If it can be server-side(the page sent to the client will be generated by the server) then yes, you can use Java

Comment: Yeah, that exactly what i wanted to do. can you show me how?

Comment: No, I'm not a Java developer, you have to do it your own(even if I think that using JS would be better)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it with java if it is a plain HTML page that you are using...
you need to use java script in this case...

However, if you are using any dynamic UI technologies like GWT... then you have option to do it using JAVA..